# How to test for success of mysqldump in PHP using shell_exec function

Tags: php, mysql, shell-exec

I am calling mysqldump via PHP to generate a backup of my database.

In my script I want to test whether or not the command completed successfully.

So far all of the solutions I have found use either 'exec' or 'system' to run mysqldump.

Those functions are disabled on my host, however 'shell_exec' is available.

Using shell_exec how can I check if the mysqldump command completed successfully, or if there was an error?

Answer (score 0):

The value that [`shell_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) returns is what the executed command outputs.

So, you should be getting all of the output from `mysqldump` inside of the return.

Now, to check whether `mysqldump` failed or not, you will most likely want to do some search in the output string that correlates with the result.

Just a quick example. If you ran `php -v` in the console, you'd get something similar like this as a result:

```
PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2015 15:59:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

This is what you'd get as a result of `shell_exec()`:

```
string(148) "PHP 5.6.10 (cli) (built: Jun 10 2015 15:59:59) Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies "
```

Comment: So the returned value will be the entire dump of the database?

Comment: No, the output will be whatever `mysqldump` outputs to the console when you run it.

Comment: I have no idea what it outputs. I don't have SSH access to try running the command myself to view the output.

Comment: Well, you can test that then, through `shell_exec()` then, right?

Comment: I can tell from personal expirence that it dont outputs anything in the console i am not sure if you can attach a parameter to get it to output

Comment: @Anoxy, well, it does not output anything *if* the dump was successful, there's plenty of errors that MySQL could throw if something went wrong. So we could conclude that if the output is empty, everything went fine? You could also check if the file is created, additionally.

Comment: @Andrius That is true indeed! And i believe that you are right if the output is empty then the dump was fine

Comment: I'm using > so that the output of the dump is sent to a file. Would that mean that any errors would also be output to that file and not returned?

Comment: No. Why would they be there? What errors are you expecting?

Comment: If I run the command with the correct info, I see no output on the screen, but the sql file is created properly. If I run the command with the wrong password, I see nothing on the screen, but the sql dump file ends up being 0kb. Seems like no matter what happens there is no output or way to tell if there was an error. If the dump worked the file is created properly, if it didn't work the file is created but at 0kb. So the only way to check for errors in this function is to run checks on the file that is created to check for file size or contents?

Comment: mysqldump --opt --host='localhost' --user='myusername' --password='mypass' 'databasename' > '/home/myaccount/public_html/test/db/test.sql'

Comment: The command works properly when all the correct info is entered. I just can't figure out how to tell when there is an error, since the only difference seems to be in the file that is created, and not what is returned and echoed to the screen.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to dump to the sql file, then load the contents of the dump file into an array, and then check if the second last line contains "Dump completed on...". There has to be an easier way than this.

Comment: I also don't understand why shell_exec cannot have the same options as exec. Why could shell_exec not have access to the return status code like exec does?